# 'Invalid controller specified' Since Moving to Modular Structure

Tags: zend-framework

I set up a Zend Framework application using Zend_Tool, but I wanted multiple modules (admin and default).
I moved the controllers, models and views for default into modules/default, then created an admin module and some controllers. I then added this line to my config file to specify the modules directory:

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
```

Since doing this, I can't get my app to work properly. If I go to http://localhost/zfproject, it works (I get the index controller/action). If I go to http://localhost/zfproject/index/, I get 'Invalid controller specified (zfproject)'.

The same message appears when going to http://localhost/zfproject/admin. It seems to think 'zfproject' is the controller I'm specifying, despite that just being the folder the project is contained in.

Thanks,
Richard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a problem I've experienced before, but ZF should detect that it is in a sub folder and work accordingly. It seems that in your case it is not doing so. There is some stuff in the manual that might help you:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.rewritebase

it'd also be interesting to see whether the app works as expected when it is in the root directory, just in case there's another problem.

Comment: Hi,
It works correctly when I set up the site root to point at the public folder.
Really have no idea why it won't work here. I had it working in the exact same way on another project last week!
Thanks,
Richard